# card game design

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, playing-cards

I'm creating a multiplayer card game.
I have two main classes:

- **Player** - represents a player in the game.
- **Manager** - is the manager of the game.. it is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and holds the the main card deck and all the Players.

My question is what is the best design for the relationship between Manager and Player.
I think that Manager should know all the players but the players should not know him...
that's because if one day I will want to use the player class for other card games it will be very generic.

In order to use my design I should create many events for the Player class.
for example `getCardFromTheDeck`.

What is the best design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design of you game should be decided heavily on your requirements, your question is too confusing this way, and not constructive.

I'll give you an example of what you are asking: I would say that an average game should have a game board, players and game controller (at very least). Board should have a collection of all the cards laid down, not drawn etc... Players should have collection of current cards they possess. Game controller should have methods like start game, determine winner etc...

For game logic you can have something like Strategy patterns, you need some way of expressing rules etc...

... and you continue thinking like this. Be aware of basic OO priciples, like [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29), most important of all Single Responsibility Principle.

For design patterns guidance that can give you ideas, refer to [GoF Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612).For more examples, find some game source codes online and study them. You will get some ideas, and from those, your design will benefit.